# Compare two csv using one column

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that runs once per day that generates a csv file with UserID, name, email. Let's say that this is a csv from yesterday

```
ID, name, email
---- ---- ----
001, John Doe, john@domain01.com
002, Jane Smith, jane@domain01.com
003, Greg Best, greg@domain01.com
```

today my csv looks different, becouse today morning someone change mail for Jane Smith, so the today's csv looks like this

```
ID, name, email
---- ---- ----
001, John Doe, john@domain01.com
002, Jane Smith, jane.smith@domain99.com
003, Greg Best, greg@domain01.com
```

I'd like to catch such a difference using PS, I mean I'd like to compare only one column (email) and get on output such csv

```
ID, name, email
---- ---- ----
002, Jane Smith, jane.smith@domain99.com
```

For now I've created such script:

```
$old = Get-Content ".\yesterday.csv"
$new = Get-Content ".\today.csv"
Compare-Object $old $new -property email -passThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }
```

But it dosn't work for me. I think that main problem is something with headers in csv. I've try a lots of things but I've lost. Could you please give me some hint how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Import-Csv instead of Get-Content in your script, possibly specifying "-delimiter ','" as a parameter.

```
$old = Import-Csv ".\yesterday.csv" -delimiter ','
$new = Import-Csv ".\today.csv" -delimiter ','
Compare-Object $old $new -property email -passThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }
```